# How to calculate the size of this table top?

Tags: calculator

Now, I have the table with legs 73cm and the table top 65x50cm.
What will be the size of this table top if legs are 48cm? Need it to save proportion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First work out how much 48cm is out of 73cm, by dividing 48 by 73. Then multiply each other dimension by that amount.

Comment: So 48÷73  = 0.657. And now 65x0.657=42.7 and 50x0.657=32.85. Right?

Comment: 48/73 = 0.657534... etc., so if you're going to round it you need to round up to 0.658. However, I would leave the answer to 48/73 on the calculator and multiply by the whole thing without rounding.

Comment: So to confirm, 0.658 x 65 = ~42.8 and 0.658 x 50 = ~32.9.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

Let's divide 48/73 to realize what will be the proportion.
And now let's take  65x50cm and multiply by the proportion that we found, so:

43X33cm

Comment: Many thanks shay.